# iBatis procedure call

Tags: java, procedure, ibatis

i can not call a procedure with ibatis. I get invalid column index error. Here is the code, i skip the myService implementation.
ERROR:
--- The error occurred in ibatis/employee.xml.
--- The error occurred while executing query procedure.
--- Check the { call GET_MY_INFO(#idNumber#,#result#) }.
--- Check the output parameters (register output parameters failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Column Index

```
<parameterMap id="getInfoCall" class="map">
    <parameter property="idNumber" jdbcType="NUMERIC" mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="result" jdbcType="CURSOR" javaType="java.sql.ResultSet" mode="OUT"/>
</parameterMap>

<procedure id="getInfo" resultClass="MyClass" parameterMap="getInfoCall">
     { call GET_MY_INFO(#idNumber#,#result#) } 
</procedure>
```

MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass{   
  private String name;  
    private String surname; 

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname)
    {
        this.surname=surname;
    }
 }



 HashMap<String,Object> params = new HashMap  <String,Object>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    params.put("idNumber", id.getValue());
    params.put("result", rs);
    ArrayList result;
    result = (ArrayList) myService.getInfo(params);
```

PROCEDURE:

```
DECLARE
ID_NUMBER NUMBER;
RESULT_P SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
ID_NO_P := ID_NUMBER;
RESULT_P := NULL;
GET_MY_INFO( ID_NUMBER, RESULT_P );
:rc0_P_CURSOR := RESULT_P;
END;
```

resultMap version:

```
   <resultMap id="result" class="map" type="MyClass" >
        <result property="name" column="NAME"/>
        <result property="surname" column="SURNAME"/>
    </resultMap>

    <procedure id="getInfo" resultMap="result" parameterMap="getInfoCall">
         { call GET_MY_INFO(#idNumber#,#result#) } 
    </procedure>
```

Comment: Why `resultClass="myClass"` ? We need to see the procedure signature, plus the output class

Comment: Just an advice: in the first year do not start with a procedure call. It just is too much hassle. Procedure call are rarely needed; queries / compley inserts are better.

Comment: Thank you. I added procedure and myclass. I didn't write this procedure and i don't have access to change it. I have to use it. Actually i have a working copy of it in mybatis but with ibatis it is not working.

Comment: Is this Oracle PLSQL? And how do you fetch the ResultSet?

Comment: Yes Oracle PLSQL. I don't think about how to fetch rs, i interested with only there is result or not.

Comment: Have you tried setting a `resultMap` for the `result` property?

Comment: yes i tried but i get "Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "resultMap" error altough it was declared

Comment: @turranor could you post that snippet with `resultMap` set?

Comment: @turranor no, you have to set the `resultMap` attribute on the `<parameter property="result" resultMap="..."` ...

Comment: i tried error is about resultmap "type" attribute

Comment: @turranor see answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I meant. Is this what you have already tried?

```
<typeAlias alias=”myTypeAlias” type=”path.to.MyClass” />

<resultMap id="myResultMap" class="myTypeAlias" >
    <result property="name" column="NAME"/>
    <result property="surname" column="SURNAME"/>
</resultMap>    

<parameterMap id="getInfoCall" class="map">
    <parameter property="idNumber" jdbcType="NUMERIC" mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="result" resultMap="myResultMap" jdbcType="CURSOR" javaType="java.sql.ResultSet" mode="OUT"/>
</parameterMap>

<procedure id="getInfo" resultClass="MyClass" parameterMap="getInfoCall">
     { call GET_MY_INFO(#idNumber#,#result#) } 
</procedure>
```

Comment: yes that is what i tried
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2124; columnNumber: 101; Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "resultMap".

lineNumber: 2124; columnNumber: 101 points the row:
<resultMap id="myResultMap" class="map" type="MyClass" >

Comment: @turranor remove the `type`, since you're saying to put everything inside a map with `class="map"`

Comment: no actually i use the full qualified name of my class

Comment: @turranor see my comment above. You can do that or leave `type` and remove `class`

Comment: yes, it worked! but now it gives java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index error

Comment: @turranor which did you remove?

Comment: i removed type and worked. when i removed class it says
Attribute "class" is required and must be specified for element type "resultMap".

Comment: @turranor see the updated answer. I added the use of a `typeAlias`

Comment: SqlMapClient operation; invalid ResultSet access for SQL []; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in ibatis/employee.xml.  
--- The error occurred while executing query procedure.  
--- Check the { call GE_MY_INFO(#idNumber#,#result#) }.  
--- Check the output parameters (register output parameters failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Comment: @turranor the procedure you added in your question lacks of the input parameters, could you add them?

Comment: @turranor you don't have the complete `CREATE PROCEDURE ...` statement?